# Form-filling iMacro keeps returning error

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to create a form-filling iMacro that inserts one column's information into the URL, and then fills out the form with the other 3 columns. However, when I try to run my script by hitting "Play (Loop)", it stops and says:

```
NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref], line 3 (Error code: -1001)
```

I checked on iMacro's [Error and Return codes](http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes) page, and it just says that error code means "Unknown error."

Here is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE /Users/codebiker/Desktop/oas/entries.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 4
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=http://mysite.org/edit?id={{!COL1}}&roleName=staff&show_dates=true#dates
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:embargo_dtmonth CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:embargo_dtday CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:embargo_dtyear CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:print_dtmonth CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:print_dtday CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:print_dtyear CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:submitManuscript ATTR=NAME:continue
```

And here is my CSV file's contents:

```
5543/498006,4,28,2013
5543/498543,4,28,2013
5543/511683,4,28,2013
5543/514471,4,28,2013
5543/516450,4,28,2013
5543/531046,4,28,2013
5543/536656,4,28,2013
5543/539213,4,28,2013
5543/542530,4,28,2013
2312/544247,4,28,2013
2312/544346,4,28,2013
2312/547729,4,28,2013
2312/548024,4,28,2013
2312/548123,4,28,2013
2312/550673,4,28,2013
2312/551341,4,28,2013
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
SET !LOOP 1
```

part. Then open the file and save it as UTF8 file and run it in iMacros.